# PendingIntent not launching /data apps

Tags: android

I have a keyguard appwidget where I'm launching a few different Intents. It seems I can launch /system apps (mms, settings etc. ) . but not /data apps ( chrome for example )

I have the following PendingIntentTemplate defined:

```
Intent startApplicationIntent = new Intent();   
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(mContext, 0, startApplicationIntent, 0);
mainLayout.setPendingIntentTemplate(R.id.stackview, pendingIntent);
```

In my RemoteViewsFactory, I have the following FillInIntent:

```
Intent i = pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage(pkgName);
i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);            
i.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
stackviewRemoteView.setOnClickFillInIntent(R.id.stackview_image, i);
```

There are no errors, the intent just unlocks the keyguard.
It also definitely isn't null as the toString() method shows the following:

```
Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=    
[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000       
pkg=com.android.chrome    
cmp=com.android.chrome/com.google.android.apps.chrome.Main }
```

Is there something special I need to do for non-system apps? I thought getLaunchIntentForPackage would give me everything I needed to launch an app the same way as it would launch if it were selected from the home screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that the way I was doing this was making a few assumptions.

PendingIntent.getActivity calls startActivity(), which requires CATEGORY_DEFAULT to be specified.

The following code is probably 'more correct' and less likely to throw errors that CATEGORY_DEFAULT can't be found:

```
Intent i = new Intent();
i.setPackage(pkgName);
i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
```